# SQL Server - Inserting Record To Many Tables At A Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert

I have a stored proc that executes insert onto 4 tables on SQL Server database. These 4 tables have exactly the same structure. How can I perform the insert at a time?

Maybe something like:

```
INSERT INTO Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4
VALUES (@p1, @p2, ....... @pn)
```

Comment: If you have four tables with exactly the same structure, it suggests that there's probably a fault in your modeling. Even more so if, as in this case, it's apparently appropriate/necessary to insert an identical row into more than one of them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever There's no fault. The reason is to seperate main records and last 24 hour records so that reading from table will not take long time for cases that I have to return a response in milliseconds.

Comment: @Damien is right.  Index on your time column and queries based on time will be fast.  By having the design you have, you're begging for data inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isnt a way - this is four separate inserts.
You could put all results into a single temp table and then select into the other tables to reduce the code, but you cannot do all four at once.

See:
[Transact-sql insert in two tables at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790630/transact-sql-insert-in-two-tables-at-once)

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert into multiple tables in a single INSERT statement. To ensure the insert into all four tables is atomic, you wrap the inserts in a [transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx). Pseudocode:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

  INSERT INTO Table1(...) VALUES(...)

  INSERT INTO Table2(...) VALUES(...)

  INSERT INTO Table3(...) VALUES(...)

  INSERT INTO Table4(...) VALUES(...)

COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to separate them, per say they cant be combined into one statement but this would work equally as well.

```
INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES (@p1, @p2)

INSERT INTO Table2
VALUES (@p1, @p2)

INSERT INTO Table3
VALUES (@p1, @p2)

INSERT INTO Table4
VALUES (@p1, @p2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set up one table to be the "master" and `INSERT` only to it. You'd then have to create a trigger on that table to push the changes into any others which need the new rows. Other posters are correct - it's four `INSERT`s, but this could simplify client code. While making it confusing as well... =/